# Why am I getting this undefined reference error while trying to build a c++ project?

Tags: compiling, gcc, c++

To fix another debug error, I added -std=c++11 to the build command. Now I'm getting a ton of "undefined reference errors like this one:

```
In function encrypt(std::string&, int)': 
/home/bob/workspace/New/Debug/../test.cpp:10: undefined reference to std::string::begin()' 
/home/bob/workspace/New/Debug/../test.cpp:10: undefined reference to std::string::end()' 
./test.o: In function main': 
/home/bob/workspace/New/Debug/../test.cpp:24: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()'" '
```

What do I need to fix ? Here's my code

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void encrypt(std::string &iostr, int key) {
key %= 26;
int ch;

for (auto &it : iostr) {
ch = tolower(it);
if (!islower(ch)) {
continue;
}
ch += key;
if (ch > 'z') {
ch -= 26;
}
it = ch;
}
}

int main() {
string source;
int key = 1;
cout
<< "Paste cyphertext and press enter to shift each letter right 1";

getline(cin, source);
encrypt(source, key);

cout << source << "";



encrypt(source, key);
cout << source << endl;
cout << "Press ENTER to exit";
cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail() + 1);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: I think you should give some information about your environment such as OS and compiler versions.

Answer (score 2):

looks like to need to install the stdc++ dev files

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++-4.8-dev
```

then to compile the code

```
g++ -o execname ./sourcefile.cpp -std=c++11
```

Comment: Thanks. I did need that update, but the same undefined reference errors persist.

Comment: odd, We'll need more to figure it out, what are your compiler and os versions `g++ --version` and `uname -srvi` and also what ide are you using?

Comment: also check to make sure you are building with g++ not gcc, if you are using gcc you'll have to add extra flags to get it to build